# How to make dynamic query in laravel 5 with model and controller

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, laravel-5

i have Add query in codeigniter like this:

in controller:

```
$data=array(
            'table'=>'tbl_activity_log',
            'val'=>array(
                         'x'=>$x,
                         'y'=>$y,
                         'z'=>$z,
       ));
$log=$this->model->add_data($data);
```

And in model add_data function like this:

```
function add_data($data)
{
  return $this->db->insert($data['table'],$this->security->xss_clean($data['val']));
}
```

But In Laravel 5 I have:

```
$name=$Request->input('name');
$lname=$Request->input('lname');
$myItems = array(
                 'first_name'=>$name,
                 'last_name'=>$lname
           );

DB::table("tbl_user")->insert($myItems);
```

My question is, how can we make table field dynamic in Laravel and call that function through model. 
Also, how can I call that function from model? Any help please. I want a dynamic query

Comment: Is there any solution for this kind of problem ???

Comment: Where have you find `$this->security->xss_clean($var)` this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a helper function

```
//create a helper function
function addModelData($arrayData = [])
{
    return \DB::table($arrayData['table'])->insert($arrayData['val']));
}

//in your controller or any place you like
$data=array(
            'table'=>'tbl_activity_log',
            'val'=>array(
                         'x'=>$x,
                         'y'=>$y,
                         'z'=>$z,
       ));
$log = addModelData($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a model as described in [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent):

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_user';

    // If your primary key is not 'id'
    protected $primaryKey = 'model_id';
}
```

Now in your controller you can use this model:

```
namespace App\Http\Controller;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller {

    public function myAction(Request $request){
        $user = new User();
        $user->last_name = $request->input('lname');
        $user->first_name = $request->input('name');
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

You also could use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment). But before you have to set the `$fillable` attribute in your model:

```
protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name'];
```

Now you can use mass assignment in your controller:

```
$user =  User::create([
    'first_name' => $request->input('name'),
    'last_name'  => $request->input('lname')
]);

// alternatively:
$user = User::create($request->only(['name', 'lname']));
```